# ForEach loop inside associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following foreach loop

```
$selectedids = "1255;1256;1257";
$selectedidsarr = explode(';', $selectedids);
$idstand = '1';
foreach ($selectedidsarr as $item) {

    $output1 = $idstand++;
    echo "<li>product_id_$output1 = $item,</li>";
}
```

I want to add the output of the above loop inside following associative array

```
          $paramas = array(
                'loginId' => $cred1,
                'password' => $credpass1,
                'orderId' =>    $orderid,
                'offer' => $offerid,
                'shipid' => $shipcharge
)
```

So that the final array will look like this;

```
          $paramas = array(
                'loginId' => $cred1,
                'password' => $credpass1,
                'orderId' =>    $orderid,
                'offer' => $offerid,
                'shipid' => $shipcharge,
                'product1_id' => 1255,
                'product2_id' => 1256,
                'product3_id' => 1257,
)
```

I tried creating following solution but its not working for me

```
$selectedids = $boughtitem;
$selectedidsarr = explode(';', $selectedids);
$idstand = '1';

foreach ($selectedidsarr as $item) {
    $idoutput1 = $idstand++;
    $paramas [] = array (  
    'product$idoutput1_id' => $item,
        );
}
```

Need advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to define a new array, just set the key of the current array to the value you want, in the form of `$array[$key] = $value` to get an array that looks like `[$key=>$value]`, or in your case...

```
$paramas['product' . $idoutput1 . '_id'] = $item;
```

Comment: or even `"product$idoutput1_id"`

Comment: Well, no, that'll show the results of `"product"` concatted with the `$idoutput1_id` variable.

Comment: _Well, no, that'll show the results.._ not if you use `"` instead of single `'`

Comment: `$idoutput1 = 1; print("|"); print("product$idoutput1_id"); print("|");` Output: **|product|**.  Isn't this supposed to print out "product1_id"?  Well, it doesn't.  Demo: https://ideone.com/wJhS6j   See the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php